# Cascading dropdowns, second one doesn't always keep change

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have two cascading dropdowns for the user to pick a Client and then a Location. The dropdowns work fine. After the user picks the Location, I have textboxes that are filled based on that data. What is happening is that after the Location is picked, most times the textboxes are filled with the correct data. Then the Location dropdown seems to randomly pick a different location to display. Sometimes the dropdown picks that same incorrect location multiple times. Sometimes it's a different location. Almost all the time it's different from the location that was set into the textboxes.

The relevant aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="NewJob.aspx.vb" Inherits="JobsApp.NewJob" EnableEventValidation="false" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<style>
.ui-autocomplete { 
    cursor:pointer; 
    height:200px; 
    font-size:medium;
    font-family:Calibri;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    text-align:left;
}    
</style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <script>
        //Script must be placed in body of form so the pagerequestmanager will work.
    $(document).ready(function () {
        BindControls();
    });
    //Calls BindControls on partial page refresh so autocomplete field will work.
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(BindControls);
    function BindControls() {
    $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "ServiceCS.asmx/GetScopes",
            data: "{ 'sLookUP': '" + request.term + "' }",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                    return {
                        value: item,
                    }
                }))
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
    },
    select: function (e, i) {
        $("#<%=txtScopeID.ClientID%>").val(i.item.value);
    },
    minLength: 0,
    scroll: true
    }).focus(function () {
    $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
    })
    }
</script>
<asp:Table runat="server" BackColor="LightGray">
<asp:TableRow BackColor="LightGray">
    <asp:TableCell ColumnSpan="6">
    <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" TabStripPlacement="Top">
    <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" ID="JobPanel" HeaderText="Job Info">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="left_column">
                <%--hidden fields needed for table joins to save data--%>
                <asp:Label ID="lblClient" runat="server" Text="Client:"></asp:Label>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfClientLocationID" runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfClientID" runat="server" />
            </td>
            <td class="right_column">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClient" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlClient_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="cddlClient" runat="server" Category="ClientID" LoadingText="Loading..." PromptText="Select Client" ServiceMethod="GetClients" ServicePath="~/ServiceCS.asmx" TargetControlID="ddlClient">
                </ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown>
            </td>
            <td class="right_column">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLoc" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlLoc_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="cdlLocs" 
                    runat="server" 
                    Category="ClientLocationID" 
                    LoadingText="Loading..." 
                    ParentControlID="ddlClient" 
                    PromptText="Select Location" 
                    PromptValue="" 
                    ServiceMethod="GetLocations" 
                    ServicePath="~/ServiceCS.asmx" 
                    TargetControlID="ddlLoc">
                </ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel2" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="right_column">
                <input type="text" id="txtSearch" name="txtSearch" style="text-align:left; width:300px;" />
            </td>
            <td class="right_column">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtScopeID" CssClass="IDbox" Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
    </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>
    </asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

The relevant vb code behind:

```
Protected Sub ddlLoc_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("xConnectionString").ConnectionString)
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim sql As String = ""
    Dim cliLocTmp As String = ""
    Dim cliCodeTmp As String = ""
    Dim cliLocReset As String = ""
    cliCodeTmp = ddlClient.SelectedItem.Text
    cliCodeTmp = Trim(Left(cliCodeTmp, InStr(cliCodeTmp, " |")))
    cliLocReset = ddlLoc.SelectedItem.Text
    cliLocTmp = ddlLoc.SelectedItem.Text
    cliLocTmp = Trim(Left(cliLocTmp, InStr(cliLocTmp, " |")))
    sql &= "SELECT ClientLocationID"
    sql &= "     , ClientName"
    sql &= "     , CliLocNumber"
    sql &= "     , CliLocName"
    sql &= "     , CliLocCity"
    sql &= "     , CliLocState"
    sql &= "     , CliLocZip"
    sql &= "     , CliLocLocation"
    sql &= "     , CliLocManager"
    sql &= "     , CliLocPhone"
    sql &= "     , CliLocNotes"
    sql &= "  FROM view_ClientLocCombo vclc inner join Client c on vclc.ClientID = c.ClientID"
    sql &= " WHERE c.clientcode = '" & cliCodeTmp & "'"
    sql &= "   AND CliLocNumber = '" & cliLocTmp & "'"
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, con)
    adp.SelectCommand = cmd
    adp.Fill(dt)
    If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        txtManager.Text = dt.Rows(0)(8).ToString
        txtPhone.Text = dt.Rows(0)("CliLocPhone").ToString
        txtName.Text = dt.Rows(0)("CliLocName").ToString
        txtAddress.Text = dt.Rows(0)("CliLocLocation").ToString
        txtCity.Text = dt.Rows(0)("CliLocCity").ToString
        txtState.Text = dt.Rows(0)("CliLocState").ToString
        txtZip.Text = dt.Rows(0)("CliLocZip").ToString
        txtNotes.Text = dt.Rows(0)("CliLocNotes").ToString
        hfClientLocationID.Value = dt.Rows(0)("ClientLocationID").ToString
        toptxtCLICODE.Text = cliCodeTmp
        toptxtCLILOCNO.Text = dt.Rows(0)("CliLocNumber").ToString
        toptxtCITYST.Text = dt.Rows(0)("CliLocCity").ToString & ", " & dt.Rows(0)("CliLocState").ToString
        toptxtDESC.Text = dt.Rows(0)("CliLocNotes").ToString
        ' Populates correct value on breakpoint. Is populated with incorrect value in browser.
        ddlLoc.SelectedItem.Text = cliLocReset
    End If
    dt.Clear()
    dt.Dispose()
    adp.Dispose()
End Sub
Protected Sub ddlClient_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    txtManager.Text = ""
    txtPhone.Text = ""
    txtName.Text = ""
    txtAddress.Text = ""
    txtCity.Text = ""
    txtState.Text = ""
    txtZip.Text = ""
    txtNotes.Text = ""
    hfClientLocationID.Value = ""
End Sub
    Protected Sub btnQuickSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnQuickSearch.Click
        Me.btnQuickSearch.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return QuickSearchPopup()")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Entire web method:

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Imports AjaxControlToolkit
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Web.Script.Services
' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class ServiceCS
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetClients(knownCategoryValues As String) As CascadingDropDownNameValue()
Dim query As String = "SELECT ClientCode + ' | ' + ClientName"
query &= "     , ClientID"
query &= "  FROM view_ClientCombo"
query &= " ORDER BY ClientCode"
Dim clients As List(Of CascadingDropDownNameValue) = GetData(query)
Return clients.ToArray()
End Function
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetLocations(knownCategoryValues As String) As CascadingDropDownNameValue()
Dim client As String = CascadingDropDown.ParseKnownCategoryValuesString(knownCategoryValues)("ClientId")
'Dim query As String = String.Format("SELECT CliLocNumber FROM view_ClientLocation WHERE ClientID = {0}", client)
Dim query As String = String.Format("SELECT CliLocNumber + ' | ' + CliLocCity + ' | ' + CliLocState, replace(CliLocName, '''', '''''') FROM dbo.view_ClientLocCombo WHERE ClientID = {0}", client)
Dim locations As List(Of CascadingDropDownNameValue) = GetData(query)
Return locations.ToArray()
End Function
Private Function GetData(query As String) As List(Of CascadingDropDownNameValue)
Dim conString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("HANDYMANConnectionString").ConnectionString
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query)
Dim values As New List(Of CascadingDropDownNameValue)()
Using con As New SqlConnection(conString)
con.Open()
cmd.Connection = con
Using reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    While reader.Read()
        values.Add(New CascadingDropDownNameValue() With { _
         .name = reader(0).ToString(), _
         .value = reader(1).ToString() _
        })
    End While
    reader.Close()
    con.Close()
    Return values
End Using
End Using
End Function
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetScopes(ByVal sLookUP As String) As String()
Dim scopes As New List(Of String)()
Using conn As New SqlConnection()
conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("HANDYMANConnectionString").ConnectionString
Using cmd As New SqlCommand()
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT JobScopeDesc, JobScopeID FROM view_JobScopeCode where JobScopeDesc like '%' + @SearchText + '%' ORDER BY JobScopeDesc"
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", sLookUP)
    cmd.Connection = conn
    conn.Open()
    Using sdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While sdr.Read()
            scopes.Add(String.Format("{0}-{1}", sdr("JobScopeDesc").ToString(), sdr("JobscopeID")))
        End While
    End Using
    conn.Close()
End Using
Return scopes.ToArray()
End Using
End Function
End Class
```

Edited to add all aspx code and the autopostback code for the first dropdown, on request.

Edited to add all vb.NET code behind, on request. Left out error checking code, this is at the limit of the question box.

Edit: This code stops calling the code-behind after testing it with more than 10 selections from the ddlloc dropdown.

Edited to pare down the code, on request.

Edit: The dropdown shows the right value when the page initially comes back after filling in the textboxes. Then the page flickers and the wrong value is selected in the dropdown. This sounds like a second page load, but when I walk through the code, the debugger does not go to the page load method a second time. And if it did, it would show the "select a location" entry in the dropdown. I really want to award this bounty.

Comment: Since ddlLoc does a post back, your problem might be in the OnInit/OnLoad.

Comment: How would I address that?

Comment: i haven't used the ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown for a while so this might not be relevant. is OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlClient_SelectedIndexChanged" being used? is it necessary?

Comment: Yes, I use that to clear the textboxes that will hold the address, city, state, zip, and comments that come up for that particular client after the user selects a location from the second dropdownlist. `ddlLoc_SelectedIndexChanged` populates those textboxes with the information after a database lookup based on the Location Number that is returned from the selection on the Location dropdownlist.

Comment: I have inspected your code and even set up a test environment that is able to execute the code more or less the same way that you must have it (you obviously haven't included all of your code and since I don't have access to your database I am faking the data). The code you posted works great. Everything works for me and never does it select a different location than the one that I select.

Comment: You either have some other code that is interfering or else there is an issue with the database where it is grabbing data incorrectly on postback. Please post all of your code or else we can only guess what your problem may be.

Comment: I'm happy to post my code but it is a lot. It's the aspx that's so big. One moment.

Comment: @JoeyJoeJoeJrShabadoo I added all the aspx code, not as long as I thought.

Comment: I used your full aspx code and even created a test database so that I didn't have to change much to get it working and everything works fine. I uploaded a video of me using the client and location dropdowns and I get all the values that I would expect: [http://tinypic.com/r/nnkxa8/8](http://tinypic.com/r/nnkxa8/8). Are you getting any javascript errors maybe? Are you maybe clicking other buttons or doing something else that I am not doing in the video? Is it always the same client / location combinations that give problems? If so maybe there is a problem with your views or database itself.

Comment: I should also mention that in the code you posted, the `ddlClient_SelectedIndexChanged` event is never run so I changed the `ddlClient` html code to this: `<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClient" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlClient_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>` but that shouldn't create any kind of problem with it selecting the wrong data like you are experiencing.

Comment: I saw that your code works, and I added `AutoPostBack="true"` but it's still happening. The very first Client, then the very first Location, and the right values showed up in the address boxes but the wrong value was in the drop down. I don't know what else to do. I'll check my code again, but I'm thinking I'm just not going to get this to work. Thanks for doing so much to try to help. :)

Comment: @JoeyJoeJoeJrShabadoo I even added these lines: `cliLocReset = ddlLoc.SelectedItem.Text` before `cliCodeTmp = ddlClient.SelectedItem.Text` and then after `toptxtDESC.Text = dt.Rows(0)("CliLocNotes").ToString` I added `ddlLoc.SelectedItem.Text = cliLocReset` but it still didn't work. Does something run after `ddlLoc_SelectedIndexChanged` that I'm not seeing?

Comment: @pixelmeow again, the code that you have posted works without issues. However, you didn't post your master page code, do you have any vb code in there that could be interfering? I also assume you have more vb code to your NewJob.aspx file that you haven't posted. If you don't mind posting the rest of the code I can check it out here and try to emulate the problem. The other thing you can do is identify if it always fails with certain data or does it fail randomly? Especially if its not random you can follow it along in the debugger to find the issue.

Comment: I'll post the rest, give me a few minutes to format it.

Comment: @JoeyJoeJoeJrShabadoo I'm sorry about the formatting but as it was it went over 600 characters over the limit. I left out the error checking on the dates and mandatory text boxes in the `SaveAll` procedure and removed all blank lines, also removed indentation in the web methods. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @JoeyJoeJoeJrShabadoo and the only things in the master page are script and css stuff in the `head` section and loading the menuitems for the `web.sitemap`.

Comment: @pixelmeow unfortunately there are no issues with the rest of the code you posted. Everything continues to work as expected in my tests and I do not see anything in the code that would interfere in any way.

Comment: My best suggestion at this point is to set a breakpoint inside the `ddlLoc_SelectedIndexChanged` event. I would specifically set the breakpoint on the line `Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, con)` and then check the values of `ddlClient.SelectedItem.Text` and `ddlLoc.SelectedItem.Text`. Do the contain the values that you expect? Also try taking the sql command from the sql variable at that point and manually run the query in sql management studio. Do you get the expected result? And does it only return one row or does it return two or more rows with different data?

Comment: I did that, and when it gets to the line `ddlLoc.SelectedItem.Text = cliLocReset`, the text is the same as it was when I selected it, and it's reset to the same value. I got one row from the database, the one I expected. Everything is perfect until the page finishes loading, and the wrong value is in the dropdown. Sometimes, it's the same wrong value even if I choose different values to start with.

Comment: There _is a lot_ of code here to sift through, are you able to cut out any parts that _definitely_ aren't causing the issue?

Comment: Absolutely. Previous commenters etc asked for more code, I'll weed-whack for you.

Comment: Code pared down, let me know if it needs more. I don't know if the dropdowns and the autocomplete are fighting with each other. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinBrown, can you see anything in my pared down code? Sorry I didn't tag you yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like possibly your Ajax request is cached.

try (cache: false)
like so:

```
source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "ServiceCS.asmx/GetScopes",
      cache: false,
            data: "{ 'sLookUP': '" + request.term + "' }",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                    return {
                        value: item,
                    }
                }))
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
    },
```